# Xwiki Confluence xml Import Error NoSuchMethod

Tags: confluence, xwiki

I am trying to import on-premise confluence instance to xwiki and always I get the following error in the middle of import regardless of how small the import is:

```
'void org.xwiki.rendering.internal.parser.wikimodel.WikiModelParserUtils.parseInline(org.xwiki.rendering.parser.StreamParser, java.lang.String, org.xwiki.rendering.listener.Listener, boolean)'
class java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.xwiki.rendering.internal.parser.wikimodel.WikiModelParserUtils.parseInline(org.xwiki.rendering.parser.StreamParser, java.lang.String, org.xwiki.rendering.listener.Listener, boolean)'
    at org.xwiki.contrib.confluence.parser.xhtml.internal.wikimodel.ConfluenceXWikiGeneratorListener.onReference(ConfluenceXWikiGeneratorListener.java:180)
    at org.xwiki.rendering.wikimodel.impl.InternalWikiScannerContext.onReference(InternalWikiScannerContext.java:1093)
    at org.xwiki.rendering.wikimodel.impl.WikiScannerContext.onReference(WikiScannerContext.java:621)
    at org.xwiki.contrib.confluence.parser.xhtml.internal.wikimodel.LinkTagHandler.end(LinkTagHandler.java:87)
    at org.xwiki.rendering.wikimodel.xhtml.handler.TagHandler.endElement(TagHandler.java:85)
    at org.xwiki.rendering.wikimodel.xhtml.impl.TagContext.endElement(TagContext.java:81)
    at org.xwiki.rendering.wikimodel.xhtml.impl.TagStack.endElement(TagStack.java:123)
    at org.xwiki.rendering.wikimodel.xhtml.impl.XhtmlHandler.endElement(XhtmlHandler.java:196)
    at java.xml/org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl.endElement(XMLFilterImpl.java:570)
    at org.xwiki.rendering.wikimodel.xhtml.filter.XHTMLWhitespaceXMLFilter.sendInlineEvent(XHTMLWhitespaceXMLFilter.java:302)
    at org.xwiki.rendering.wikimodel.xhtml.filter.XHTMLWhitespaceXMLFilter.sendPreviousContent(XHTMLWhitespaceXMLFilter.java:291)
    at org.xwiki.rendering.wikimodel.xhtml.filter.XHTMLWhitespaceXMLFilter.flushContent(XHTMLWhitespaceXMLFilter.java:332)
    at org.xwiki.rendering.wikimodel.xhtml.filter.XHTMLWhitespaceXMLFilter.flushContent(XHTMLWhitespaceXMLFilter.java:314)
    at org.xwiki.rendering.wikimodel.xhtml.filter.XHTMLWhitespaceXMLFilter.endElement(XHTMLWhitespaceXMLFilter.java:183)
    at org.xwiki.contrib.confluence.parser.xhtml.internal.wikimodel.ConfluenceXHTMLWhitespaceXMLFilter.endElement(ConfluenceXHTMLWhitespaceXMLFilter.java:90)
    at java.xml/org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl.endElement(XMLFilterImpl.java:570)
    at org.xwiki.rendering.wikimodel.xhtml.filter.AccumulationXMLFilter.endElement(AccumulationXMLFilter.java:86)
    at java.xml/org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl.endElement(XMLFilterImpl.java:570)
    at org.xwiki.rendering.wikimodel.xhtml.filter.DTDXMLFilter.endElement(DTDXMLFilter.java:86)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.endNamespaceScope(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleEndElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at java.xml/org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl.parse(XMLFilterImpl.java:357)
    at org.xwiki.rendering.wikimodel.xhtml.filter.DefaultXMLFilter.parse(DefaultXMLFilter.java:58)
    at java.xml/org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl.parse(XMLFilterImpl.java:357)
    at org.xwiki.rendering.wikimodel.xhtml.filter.DefaultXMLFilter.parse(DefaultXMLFilter.java:58)
    at java.xml/org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl.parse(XMLFilterImpl.java:357)
    at org.xwiki.rendering.wikimodel.xhtml.filter.DefaultXMLFilter.parse(DefaultXMLFilter.java:58)
    at org.xwiki.rendering.wikimodel.xhtml.XhtmlParser.parse(XhtmlParser.java:134)
    at org.xwiki.rendering.internal.parser.wikimodel.AbstractWikiModelParser.parse(AbstractWikiModelParser.java:134)
    at org.xwiki.contrib.confluence.parser.xhtml.internal.ConfluenceXHTMLParser.parse(ConfluenceXHTMLParser.java:246)
    at org.xwiki.rendering.internal.parser.wikimodel.AbstractWikiModelParser.parse(AbstractWikiModelParser.java:114)
    at org.xwiki.contrib.confluence.parser.xhtml.internal.ConfluenceXHTMLInputFilterStream.read(ConfluenceXHTMLInputFilterStream.java:115)
    at org.xwiki.contrib.confluence.parser.xhtml.internal.ConfluenceXHTMLInputFilterStream.read(ConfluenceXHTMLInputFilterStream.java:47)
    at org.xwiki.filter.input.AbstractBeanInputFilterStream.read(AbstractBeanInputFilterStream.java:79)
    at org.xwiki.contrib.confluence.filter.internal.input.ConfluenceInputFilterStream.parse(ConfluenceInputFilterStream.java:817)
    at org.xwiki.contrib.confluence.filter.internal.input.ConfluenceInputFilterStream.convertToXWiki21(ConfluenceInputFilterStream.java:786)
    at org.xwiki.contrib.confluence.filter.internal.input.ConfluenceInputFilterStream.readPageRevision(ConfluenceInputFilterStream.java:644)
    at org.xwiki.contrib.confluence.filter.internal.input.ConfluenceInputFilterStream.readPageRevision(ConfluenceInputFilterStream.java:559)
    at org.xwiki.contrib.confluence.filter.internal.input.ConfluenceInputFilterStream.readPage(ConfluenceInputFilterStream.java:447)
    at org.xwiki.contrib.confluence.filter.internal.input.ConfluenceInputFilterStream.readInternal(ConfluenceInputFilterStream.java:202)
    at org.xwiki.contrib.confluence.filter.internal.input.ConfluenceInputFilterStream.read(ConfluenceInputFilterStream.java:138)
    at org.xwiki.contrib.confluence.filter.internal.input.ConfluenceInputFilterStream.read(ConfluenceInputFilterStream.java:84)
    at org.xwiki.filter.input.AbstractBeanInputFilterStream.read(AbstractBeanInputFilterStream.java:79)
    at org.xwiki.filter.internal.job.FilterStreamConverterJob.runInternal(FilterStreamConverterJob.java:97)
    at org.xwiki.job.AbstractJob.runInContext(AbstractJob.java:243)
    at org.xwiki.job.AbstractJob.run(AbstractJob.java:220)
    at org.xwiki.filter.script.internal.ScriptFilterStreamConverterJob.run(ScriptFilterStreamConverterJob.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

I am not a Java person and I really don't know what it really means. Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The XWiki API used by XWiki Extension Confluence XML 9.14.4 has been changed and is now breaking the Confluence XML import, beginning with XWiki 13.10.4 and 14.2.

XWiki Jira issue XRENDERING-6 is causing the NoSuchMethodError:
https://jira.xwiki.org/browse/XRENDERING-6

XWiki Extension Confluence XML Jira issue CONFLUENCE-103 has been created to fix the issue:
https://jira.xwiki.org/browse/CONFLUENCE-103

What can you do?
Either wait until CONFLUENCE-103 has been fixed in XWiki Extension Confluence XML 9.14.4+. Or use a XWiki release older than 13.10.4, eg. 13.10.3.
For me Confluence XML import worked as expected using XWiki 13.10.3

Comment: Thanks.. Thanks.. Thanks.. It indeed work. I was struggling with it from almost a week. You really saved my life. I installed 13.10.3 on docker and tried migration. It worked for one space without any hiccups and I am certain it will work for other spaces as well. My RHEL installation was just one version off. I have 13.10.4 unfortunately. Thanks again

Comment: Jira issue XRENDERING-6 has been fixed and XWiki Extension Confluence XML 9.14.5 (including fix for XRENDERING-6) has been released:
https://extensions.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Extension/Confluence/#H9.14.5

You could give it a try with XWiki 13.10.5 and Confluence XML 9.14.5.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your update. I truly appreciate that. I am certainly going to try it out and keep you informed. We are actively migrating Confluence to Xwiki. I will update confluence extension on my XWiki 13.10.5 and try it out. That will make our life easier as I don't have to export it from 13.10.3 and Import it into 13.10.5